Resuming from suspend disables laptop keyboard
How do you fix a non responsive keyboard after resuming a laptop from suspend?
I recently swapped out a broken keyboard on a Dell Precision 5520 running Ubuntu 22. At first boot, the new keyboard worked fine. However, I noticed that if I closed the laptop lid and reopen, the keyboard no longer works. Everything else is fine.
Plus, if I reboot, the keyboard works again, so I'm guessing it's some subtle software issue, although I'm not sure why it would start after replacing hardware with identical hardware.
I also noticed that Gnome no longer locks the screen after suspend. After resuming, my desktop is open and unlocked, so maybe the new keyboard is interring with the suspend somehow?
I've determined the keyboard appears as file /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4 because that file is missing after suspend.
Before suspend, running sudo dmesg | egrep "i8042|input4" returns:
[    1.222083] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    1.222398] i8042: Warning: Keylock active
[    1.224727] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.224732] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.226700] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
[    6.522572] dell_laptop: Using i8042 filter function for receiving events
[   20.488693] input: PS/2 Generic Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6

And after suspend, it returns the identical output, so nothing new appears to be happening with i8042.
Edit:
If I activate suspend with:
systemctl suspend

resume and then check:
journalctl --system --boot=0 --priority=4

the only line that looks suspicious and related to the keyboard is:
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x411, Reinit

However, using some other guides, I noticed that the keyboard corresponds to /sys/class/input/input4 and after suspend, that file vanishes. Could these be related?
Since the keyboard works after reboot, even if there's a hardware fault, there's a state where it works, so is there any way to programmaticaly reset the device, to simulate it coming out of a reboot instead of suspend, to get it working again?
Other solutions I've tried, which had no effect:

I've tried forcing devices to be rescanned with:
sudo udevadm trigger --action=add

Rebinding the input subsystem with:
sudo modprobe -r usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
sudo modprobe -r hid_generic
sudo modprobe hid_generic


(Those fail because those modules are in-use.)

Restarting udev:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-udevd

Reloading the i8042 module:
sudo rmmod i8042
sudo modprobe i8042


(That fails because it says that module is built-in and can't be removed or reloaded.)

I've tried rebinding i8042:
echo -n "i8042" | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/i8042/unbind
echo -n "i8042" | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/i8042/bind

Creating a udev rule to prevent 8042 from suspending:
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-i8042-autosuspend.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="serio", KERNEL=="serio0", ATTR{power/control}="on"
sudo udevadm control --reload
sudo reboot

Adding the grub parameters i8042.reset=1, i8042.nomux=1, i8042.noaux, i8042.kbdreset, and i8042.probe_defer to my GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub.


Nothing works.
Is there anything else I haven't tried?

I'm not sure why but adding i8042.dumbkbd to my GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT appears to have fixed the problem.
If I had to guess, I'd say there's a bug somewhere, maybe in the keyboard firmware or the motherboard firmware, that's causing the system to not tell the keyboard to resume from suspend. Whereas i8042.dumbkbd tells the kernel to not bother writing any information to the i8042 keyboard, presumably stopping it from powering down on suspend and therefore working on resume.

Hmm, you could install gnome-tweaks if you don't already have it, and then open
gnome-tweaks -> General tab -> Toggle the "Suspend when laptop lid is closed" switch to off
